# leaflet rectangle disappears instantly

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm just getting started creating a Leaflet webapp and I'm failing to draw a rectangle. When I load the page it shows for a split second, barely before the map even loads, and then it disappears (That's in Chrome, in Firefox it doesn't show at all). What am I missing here?

Below is my code:

```
<script>
    var bounds = [[52.42, 4.78], [52.46, 4.88]];
    var map = L.map('map', {

    maxBounds: bounds,
    minZoom: 14


    }).setView([52.44, 4.83], 14);

    var googleLayer = new L.Google('ROADMAP');
    map.addLayer(googleLayer);

    $(document).ready(function() {
        L.rectangle(bounds, {color: "red", weight: 1}).addTo(map);
    });
</script>
```

I tried drawing the rectangle at the $(document).ready() event but that didn't work.

Comment: Look in your web inspector and see if the node has been removed or if it is just hidden. I can't help you much more than that since I am not familiar with google APIs.

Answer (score 1):

The rectangle is hidden because the google layer gets drawn on top. Might be a bug, I would expect the layers to be in the z-order in which they get added. Quick fix (check for side effects) is to force the needed order using CSS styles such as these:

```
.leaflet-google-layer{
    z-index: 0 !important;
}
.leaflet-map-pane{
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Very logical explaination as well!